# postman automatetest helpme pls

Tags: testing, postman

I'm not good at English (;--;)

I have a postman test

```
pm.expect(responseJson.info.5a1b2c3d4g4t5e6).to.be.a('object'); });
```

5a1b2c3d4g4t5e6 <<< What should I do?

[image]

thank you

Comment: At least provide all information, error messages, your code. This is not possible to answer, since I don't know what you're asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pm.expect(responseJson.info["5a1b2c3d4g4t5e6"]).to.be.a('object')
```

try calling the property like this

. notation for calling property doesn't work if the property name starts with number or special characters. In that case you can use bracket notation to call the property

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

For dot notation the property name should be a valid javascript identifier , name starting with numbers are not valid identifiers